# Looking for a self-contained equation rendering library

Tags: python, parsing, latex, equation, mathml

Is there such a thing as a small, self-contained library that will render an equation written in a text-based format (e.g. LaTeX or MathML) to an image (either vector or raster)?

It would be preferable if it's in Python or Python-friendly.

(One possibility that I've found: [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) has Python code to parse and display LaTeX equations, using gl2ps. If I don't find anything else it seems possible to extract all the relevant bits into a separate library.)

**EDIT:** by "self-contained" I mean they can't use TeX/LaTex itself since unfortunately I can't rely on it being installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to [convert MathML to SVG](http://www.grigoriev.ru/svgmath/).

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the only one that doesn't depend on LaTeX, I'll probably end up using it.

Comment: @AntiEarth: The site appears to be down. Here is the sourceforge link http://sourceforge.net/projects/svgmath/

Answer (score 1):

There's mimetex a stand alone program for rendering latex math... it's not a library however

http://www.forkosh.com/mimetex.html

Answer (score 0):

A versatile program and Python module to allow conversion of LaTeX math equations in to PNG images: http://code.google.com/p/latexmath2png/ (MIT license, relies on `dvipng`).

Comment: While it looks nice, it [requires LaTeX installed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1838411/321973)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this meets your requirements, but I knew MoinMoin has had latex extensions for a while so I looked again and found this:

[MoinMoin Latex Support](http://johannes.sipsolutions.net/Projects/new-moinmoin-latex)

You should be able to take this code and re-use it in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try ReforMath (http://reformath.webnode.com). It is C++ based and runs under both Windows and Linux. Although unfinished, it can render a number MathML elements.

Comment: It is no longer available.