# Running gunicorn in python optimized mode

Tags: django, performance, gunicorn

By optimized mode I mean no asserts, possibly no doc strings, `.pyo` rather then `.pyc`.

In short I have a django project runnning through gunicorn(v18.0) in the standard style (`gunicorn 'module.wsgi:application'`)

I have been unable to find a reference in the docs or elsewhere online.

Comment: The maintainer [recommends](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/592#issuecomment-30316178) using [environment variables](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables) for what would otherwise be command line options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `PYTHONOPTIMIZE` environment variable if you really understand what you are doing.

```
# e.g.
# same as -O
export PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1
# same as -OO
export PYTHONOPTIMIZE=2
```

> Reference: [Python doc: Command line and environment](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html?highlight=optimization%20options#envvar-PYTHONOPTIMIZE)
>
> PYTHONOPTIMIZE
>
> If this is set to a non-empty string it is equivalent
>   to specifying the -O option. If set to an integer, it is equivalent to
>   specifying -O multiple times.

**But normally you should never do it !!!**

Deestan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/945135/1093020) for another SO question "Best practice for Python Assert" is really great:

> Asserts should be used to test conditions that should **never happen**.
>
> The purpose is to **crash early** in the case of a corrupt program state.

Usually a django application uses many other libraries. When something critical happens, and those libraries believe that the application should crash immediately, they follow the best practice above and use asserts. You don't want to break that.

Comment: `But normally you should never do it !!!` I disagree. `assert` statements are not meant for production exactly because they can be disabled by something out of your control. You should not rely on it in a production environment. See this answer from the same question https://stackoverflow.com/a/1838411/1272513

Answer (score 0):

This works, though it is not particularly elegant.

```
python -O `which gunicorn` 'module.wsgi:application'
```