# Are Python assertions crutches?

Tags: python, assertions, duck-typing

As suggested in the [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively) assertions are good for

- Checking parameter types, classes, or values
- Checking data structure invariants
- Checking "can't happen" situations (duplicates in a list, contradictory state variables)
- After calling a function, to make sure that its return is reasonable

But where is the edge between using assertions and using an 'if' statement with raising exceptions next?

For example.

```
def some_domain_operation(user, invoice):
    assert isinstance(user, (User, int))
    # Do something.
```

vs

```
def some_domain_operation(user, invoice):
    if not isinstance(user, (User, int)):
        raise ValueError()

    # Do something.
```

I think that using assertions is not reliable (could be disabled by the user), so I could not give a good example, when using assertions is better than using explicit an 'if' with `raise next`.

What is your opinion about assertions Pn python. Are they crutches?

Comment: the second example would be a `TypeError` instead of a `ValueError`.

Comment: The way I see it/I've been taught it is that exceptions are used when you want your application to recover from an error and assertions are for killing your program when something that should never, ever break, breaks. So a perfectly written program could still throw/catch exceptions but should never fail an assertion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944592/best-practice-for-python-assert

Comment: Padraic Cunningham, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, there is a big difference between `if` and `assert`:

The expression after `assert` is **never** true [1]. If it were true, your program might as well stop executing at that point because we do not know what is true any more. [2] They are just a debugging and documentation aid for the developers who look into the source code.

Literally, an assertion says "this is true at this point of program flow. Upon no circumstance would this expression evaluate to false".

Thus, an `assert` should be considered an invariant. In a correctly written module, no `assert` will ever be hit. If we consider your case:

```
assert isinstance(user, (User, int))
```

If disabling this `assert` would change the behaviour of the module, it shouldn't be an `assert` anymore, but raise a `TypeError`.

---

[1] ... in a well-behaving, correctly written program.

[2] You should **never** catch `AssertionError`, except in the circumstances when you need to catch `AssertionError`