# Writing unit test for list iterator?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Hi I'm new to Python and I just started learning how to implement array based list in Python. I made my list iterable with an iterator. I raised an error to stop iteration when the index is greater than length of list. However, when I'm writing my unit test I got this error, but I clearly raised StopIteration in my list iterator?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\task1unitTest.py", line 110, in testIter
    self.assertRaises(StopIteration, next(it1))
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ListIterator.py", line 10, in __next__
   raise StopIteration
StopIteration
```

This is my list iterator:

```
class ListIterator:
    def __init__(self,array):
        self.current=array
        self.index=0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self.current[self.index]==None:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            item_required=self.current[self.index]
            self.index+=1
            return item_required
```

Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT:
Okay this is how I tested it:

```
def testIter(self):
    a_list=List()
    a_list.append(1)
    a_list.append(2)
    a_list.append(3)
    it1=iter(a_list)
    self.assertEqual(next(it1),1)
    self.assertEqual(next(it1),2)
    self.assertEqual(next(it1),3)
    #self.assertRaises(StopIteration, next(it1))
```

The error occurs at `self.assertRaises`

Comment: An initial glance at this suggests that you stop iterating if your list contains `None`, which isn't...exactly desirable in my mind.  Could you show us how you're testing it?  That is, what list do you feed it initially and what your expectation is?

Comment: His [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50162089/1126841) implies he is initializing the array with something like `self.array = [None] * 50`, and that only non-`None` values are stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't the correct usage of [`unittest.assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).

```
self.assertRaises(StopIteration, next(it1))
```

Try this:

```
with self.assertRaises(StopIteration):
    next(it1)
```

Or this:

```
self.assertRaises(StopIteration, next, it1)
```

Comment: Alright thanks for the help.Will accept your answer when Ithe system allows me

Comment: The reason why it fails is that `next(it1)` gets evaluated *before* `assertRaises` gets called