# How to create an error message in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

I want to create an error message in Python, i.e. the program should be interrupted and an (if possible coloured) error message should be printed. For instance:

> If a == 0:
>
> > Error("a should be nonzero")

In Matlab, you can do this using the `error` instruction. How can you do this in Python? I have found [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions) but I am not sure that is what I am looking for.

Comment: just raise an error

Comment: This solved my question. I knew that it was a very basic one. I had not found the duplicate question myself. Can I delete my question?

Comment: You might as well leave your question - it can act as a portal to the linked question.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes but I will continue to lose reputation as people downvote.

Comment: On the other hand, you cannot close too many questions...

Comment: Excuse me for this duplicate question. In fact, I was not aware of the fact that "producing an error message" is called "raising (throwing) an exception".

Answer (score 1):

You can `raise` it like so:

```
if a == 0:
    raise ValueError("a should be nonzero")
```

or simply by using [`assert`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) as:

```
assert a!=0, "a should be nonzero!"
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but don't think `assert` should be used on user input, vaguely relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/945135/6260170

Comment: Yeah, asserts are for catching broken program logic, not bad data. If the user sees an AssertionError they are entitled to tell you to fix the program.

Comment: OTOH, `a` may not be user data but the result of an internal calculation that cannot possibly result in zero if the program logic is correct. And in that situation `assert` is definitely appropriate.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, I agree, when I made the comment, `a` was user input: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42489906/revisions

Comment: @Chris Indeed. But we don't know what it is in the OP's code.