# Convert float to int and raise an exception in case of rounding

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

So for example I have:

```
a = np.array(...)
a[idx / 3] = 5
```

`idx / 3` will be a `float`, even though it will always have an integer value in that program. This will raise either a `VisibleDeprecationWarning` or is already no longer supported by newer Python versions.

**Is there a built-in function that converts a float to an int and can raise an Exception if the input value is not an integer? Or what is the proper way to do it?**

I'm aware that this might also lead to some questions about 'how close' to an integer, that's why I ask and do not just trust in `floor`/`ceil`.

Comment: Why is `idx` a float? Looks a bit like a design problem in the first place?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Because division of an integer by another integer seems to result in a float, even if the number actually has integer value.

Comment: yes, if you do this with `/` in Python-3. If you use `//` however, it is integer division.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be explicit:

```
assert (idx % 3) == 0, "idx must be divisible by 3"
a[idx // 3] = 5
```

Comment: This gives ``IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`` on NumPy 1.12. You need to actually cast the result of `idx // 3` to an int

Comment: Ah, only if `idx` is a float

Comment: Be carefull, `"assert" statements are removed when the compilation is optimized`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944592/best-practice-for-using-assert/1838411#1838411