# Comparison in Python assert statement

Tags: python, assert, assertion

After checking few python open source projects I found examples where same function have test cases with `assert <>` and `assert <> is True`.

And I cannot find answer about best practices of using `assert` statement with and without full condition.

For example function

```
def is_even(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

can be tested in such way

```
assert is_even(6) is True 
assert is_even(6) == True
```

but also it can be tested like

```
assert is_even(6)
```

And here I see problem cause if function `is_even` will be changed on

```
def is_even(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return <>
    else:
        return False
```

Where `<>` can be changed on any number(except `0`) or non empty string - last test will pass. But this will be another function.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142418/what-is-the-use-of-assert-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944592/best-practice-for-python-assert) SO question about assert usage but seems they don't fully cover my question.

From another side PEP 8 [specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) have such example

- Don't compare boolean values to True or False using `==`

  ```
  Yes:   if greeting:
  No:    if greeting == True:
  Worse: if greeting is True:
  ```

But is it also about `assert` usage?

Comment: Yes, that PEP-8 advice about booleans also applies to `assert` usage. Similarly, that function should be written as: `def is_even(number):` `return number % 2 == 0`

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Comment: @DeepSpace question is about is it good practice to use for tests just `assert is_even(6)` or better to use `assert is_even(6) is True` cause function can be changed and `assert` also will pass, but this will be another function(another result will be returned)

Comment: Why would you ever return the string 'True' instead of returning `True` if what you mean is `True`? If you are using assert to check whether a function is returning the expected string then PEP8's advice about booleans isn't relevant.

Comment: Ok, doing `assert is_even(6) is True` and `assert is_even(5) is False` is reasonable, since you want to assure that `is_even` returns a boolean. OTOH, the function name implies it returns a boolean, and anyone calling it should be following PEP-8, and calling it like `if is_even(n):`, and not examining the actual value it returns.

Comment: @TBurgis it's was just example with `True` and True. maybe not best. but thanks for your input about PEP8's advice about booleans!

Comment: Also note that `assert` is often mis-used, it should only really be used for sanity checks (things that should be impossible), you should `raise` an exception for anything else like bad input data

Comment: PEP-8 is *crystal clear* on this: *Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==.*. It doesn't matter where you do this; the examples use `if` but that doesn't matter. The assertion applies to *any context*. It doesn't matter if the test is done for `if`, or `assert`, or `while`, a conditional expression or as a stand-alone expression whose result is stored in a variable.

Answer (score 4):

Code like

```
if a:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Is unclean anyway.  It should be written as `return a` or, if a bool (and not just a truish value) is necessary, `return bool(a)`.

If you use `v == True` or `v is True` is completely up to the situation.  The first would check if a value *equals* the value `True`.  Whether a value does this, is also up to the class of this value (`1 == True` is true, `1.0 == True` is true, but `1j == True` is false, for instance).

If you compare using `is`, then you make it absolutely clear that you accept the value `True` and nothing else.

In most cases, however, I assume that just stating `assert f(x)` would be the semantically correct thing to do.  For instance for an assert like `assert is_in_rectangle(point)`.  To spell that out as `assert is_in_rectangle(point) == True` or `assert is_in_rectangle(point) is True` would be wrong because any truish value (e. g. `[ 1 ]`) should suffice.  Checking for an explicit `True` as the result would be assuming too much.

So, baseline:  Don't compare truish values to `True`.  Compare result values only to `True` if you have very specific demands on the value like "must be a bool, not just truish" (which is a rare case).

Answer (score 3):

`assert` is *exactly like* `if`. It is a keyword, followed by an *boolean expression*, and it requires the expression to evaluate to `True`. The statement `assert expression` will succeed *if and only if* the `if expression` succeeds.

Given that, there are two aspects to your questions. The first `condition` vs `condition==True`. This is a matter of style. You don't write `if condition==True:`, but simply `if condition:`. Similarly, there is no reason to write

```
assert is_even(6) == True
```

Just write

```
assert is_even(6)
```

instead.

The second is `condition==True` vs `condition is True`. This is not a matter of style only. Run the following

```
if []==False:  # also: if not []
    print('false')

if bool([]) is False:
    print('false')

if [] is False:
    print('false')
```

Examples (1) and (2) will print, but example (3) will not.

`False` is a singleton value, meaning that there is *only one* `False` object in the python interpreter, and *all false objects* are *the same object*. So, using `is` feels right (just like it is considered good style to write `if object is None`). However, there is the concept of falsy/truthy values in python: `if condition` does not necessarily trigger if `condition` is false, but if `bool(condition)` is false. That's done automatically. In the example above, the empty list is a falsy value. That is `bool([])` evaluates to the `False` object (which, again, is only one). So, example (1) succeeds, because it is automatically converted (internally) to something like example (2). However, example (3) does not work, because, although an empty list *evaluates to false*, it *is not* `False`. It is an empty list. So, to sum up you example

```
if greeting: # good style, and it works
if greeting==True: # bad style, redundant, but it still works
if greeting is True: # misleading. does a different thing than it seems to do. avoid it
```

Closing comment: you give the example

```
def is_even(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return <>
    else:
        return False
```

where you mention that `<>` could be *any* truthy value. In that spirit, it would be equivalent to write

```
def is_even(number):
     return number % 2
```

since it would return non-zero (truthy) or zero (falsy). However, *don't* do that. A user of a function called `is_even` would expect the function to return `True` or `False`, not an integer. You don't know how that user is using your code (eg. might send it to a database, or web service that expects a really boolean value). So it would be better to return a boolean value. So, the shortest and safest form of the function would be to write

```
def is_even(number):
    return bool(number % 2)
```