# generating equation representations in python/on the web

Tags: python, math, latex, equations

Is it possible to take something like x^2+5 and have it generate this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0f8Q.gif

I'll be using Python so anything based in Python would work, but I'm open to other solutions such as latex output.

Comment: That image *is* LaTeX output.

Comment: @KennyTM: Are you sure ? I don't think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sympy can output LaTeX code and MathML](http://docs.sympy.org/tutorial.html#printing), from there you can create images or other forms of display, depending on what exactly you need. You'll find some methods for that in this old [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617668/looking-for-a-self-contained-equation-rendering-library).

In theory, MathML would be ideal to display equations in a browser, but not all browsers support MathML.

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at this LaTeX module for Python: http://www.pytex.org/

Answer (score 1):

May be you need [SVGMath](http://www.grigoriev.ru/svgmath/), it is pure python and converts [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/) expressions to SVG.